# First week of 2014 displayed as 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been banging my head against the wall all week trying to figure out why the first week of 2014 is displayed as 2013-01 or 2013-53, not 2014-01. Haven't used access for a few years so i'm a bit rusty and i never noticed this problem before but now my calculations are all wrong. I managed easily to correct this in PHP by using format o instead of Y.

The code i am currently using is: `FORMAT(BI.date,"yyyy-ww") AS YearWeek`. Tried both setting the optional parameters of the function (firstdayofweek, firstweekofyear) but no change. Also tried `DatePart` but with no luck.

Answer (score 5):

Your question does not provide enough detail to elicit a specific answer, but it sounds like you are mis-using the `Format()` statement you cited. The VBA test code

```vbs
Sub WeekTest()
   Dim bi_Date As Date, i As Long
   bi_Date = DateSerial(2013, 12, 30)
   For i = 1 To 5
      Debug.Print Format(bi_Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "  " & Format(bi_Date, "yyyy-ww")
      bi_Date = DateAdd("d", 1, bi_Date)
   Next
End Sub
```

produces the following results

```
2013-12-30  2013-53
2013-12-31  2013-53
2014-01-01  2014-1
2014-01-02  2014-1
2014-01-03  2014-1
```

which illustrates that the VBA `Format(bi_Date, "yyyy-ww")` call does not produce values in 2013 if the date in question *is actually in* 2014.